# Find the rate of change of perimeter when the expanding sides are 5cm

Tags: calculus

Here is a problems which seems simple but I cannot figure it out.

> Two parallel sides of a rectangle are expanding at rate 2$cm/sec$, the other two are contracting instead, until the resultant figure has 50$cm^2$ of area. Find the rate of change of perimeter at the instant when the expanding sides are $5cm$.

**Attempt:** There is no information about the initial sides, suppose we have expanding sides of $x_0\ cm$ and contracting sides of $y_0\ cm$ then the area at time $t$ it's $$(x_0+2t)(y_0-2t)=50 $$ assuming contracting sides at the same rate of expansion. The perimeter at time $t$ is $$2(x_0+2t)+2(y_0-2t)$$
if I replace $$P=2(x_0+2t)+2\cdot\frac{50}{x_0+2t}$$
Should I just compute $P'$ when $5=x_0+2t$ i.e., $t=\frac{5-x_0}{2}$? I think this is confusing.

Comment: don't assume that the contracting sides are contracting at the same rate as the expanding sides are expanding. The area is supposed to be constant, not the perimeter.

Comment: @DavidQuinn that's right, otherwise as you said the perimeter will be constant.